# Continued fraction for $c= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1{2^{2^k}} $ - is there a systematic expression?

Tags: reference-request, continued-fractions

I want to use the convergents of the continued fraction for $$c= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1{2^{2^k}} $$ - but of course a numeric software is very limited here, so I hope there exists a systematic expression for the entries of the continued fraction itself which I can use and evaluate directly.
So

> Q: is there a functional description of the terms of the continued fraction for $c$

(I have a vague memory that I had once a copy of an article which dealt with systematic, but a-periodic continued fractions possibly related to constants like $c$ here, but I cannot remember more details, so a useful reference would help as well. At least I just found an old article of J. Shallit "Simple continued fractions for some irrational numbers" which discusses this but only for series with bases $3$ instead of $2$ in the denominators $c_3= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1{3^{2^k}} $ , and also I do not get the recipe to determine the entries of the continued fractions correctly)

Using Pari/GP with internal decimal precision of \p 200 I get the following:

```
 c = sum(k=0,24,(2.0)^-(2^k))*1.0   \\ generate an approximation
 %575 = 0.816421509022              \\ result: first digits of the constant
 contfrac(c)
 %574 = [0, 1, 4, 2, 4, 4, 6, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 6, 4, 4, 2,
         4, 6, 2, 4, 4, 6, 4, 2, 6, 4, 2, 4, 6, 4, 4, 2, 4,
         6, 2, 4, 4, 6, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 6, 4, 4, 2, 6, 4, 
         2, 4, 4, 6, 4, 2, 6, 4, 2, 4, 6, 4, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2,
         4, 4, 6, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 6, 4, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, 4,
         4, 6, 4, 2, 6, 4, 2, 4, 6, 4, 4, 2, 6, 4, 2, 4, 4,
         6, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 6, 4, 4, 2, 6, 4, 2, 4, 4, 6,
         4, 2, 6, 4, 2, 4, 6, 4, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 4, 6, 4,
         2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 6, 4, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 4, 6, 4, 2,
         6, 4, 2, 4, 6, 4, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 4, 6, 4, 2, 4]
```

Comment: Since the binary expansion of the number is straightforward, eg. $0.1101000100000001\cdots$ perhaps the terms and convergents should be sought first in binary form.

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A007400](https://oeis.org/A007400), which has a recurrence formula.

Comment: @RobertIsrael - upps, of course the OEIS. Should have thought of that myself... Thanks for the hint

Comment: Also the numerators and denominators of the convergents in A073414 and A073415.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Shallit's paper, which you've cited, gives a simple algorithm for generating these coefficients.  It works for $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}u^{-2^k}$ for integer $u\ge 3$; but he notes that it also works for $u=2$ (your case) with a slight modification.

Start with
$$B_1=[1,3].$$
Then repeatedly apply the following rule: $B_{n+1}$ is generated from $B_n$ by appending the reverse of $B_n$ to $B_n$ and then adding $1$ and $-1$ to the two central terms.  That is,
$$
B_2=[1,4,2,1] \\
B_3=[1,4,2,2,0,2,4,1] \\
B_4=[1,4,2,2,0,2,4,2,0,4,2,0,2,2,4,1] \\
...
$$
This is correct as it stands, but generally one excludes zeroes from the entries of a continued fraction.  To rectify that (this is the slight modification), generate $C_n$ from $B_n$ by contracting any subsequence $[a,0,b]$ down to $[a+b]$.  That is,
$$
C_2=[1,4,2,1] \\
C_3=[1,4,2,{\mathbf{4}},4,1] \\
C_4=[1,4,2,{\mathbf{4}},4,{\mathbf{6}},{\mathbf{4}},2,4,1]\\
...
$$
Now the elements of each $C_n$ (except the final $1$) are the entries in the continued fraction for $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2^{-2^{k}}$.  (You'll note that they agree with the ones you've already found.)  Just choose a large enough $n$ to get to the entry you need.

Comment: Ah, thank you - my answer just crossed yours, sorry. Sometimes it is even easier to do pattern-detection on your own and understand it... But I can now use the article of J. Shallit as better reference, thank you for the work to explain this!

Answer (score 1):

Ah, at least one empirical pattern which can be built recursively (if that heuristic holds...)
Let $$a(n) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac 1{2^{2^k}} $$
and let $ c(n) $ be the list of partial denominators of the continued fraction (="entries" of the cf) of $a(n)$ - written as a string because we have only few numbers and can nicely compact the notation to focus on the **pattern** in the entries. Also let the last entry be unnormalized, so split the last entry $e$ into two entries $e-1,1$ then we get the patterns:

```
c(2)=[0;1 4 2 1]
c(3)=[0;1 4 2 4 4 1]
c(4)=[0;1 4 2 4 4 6 4 2 4 1]
c(5)=[0;1 4 2 4 4 6 4 2 4 6 2 4 6 4 4 2 4 1]
c(6)=[0;1 4 2 4 4 6 4 2 4 6 2 4 6 4 4 2 4 6 2 4 4 6 4 2 6 4 2 4 6 4 4 2 4 1]
```

From $c(3)$ to $c(4)$ and then for $c(4)$ to $c(5)$ we find a simple recursive pattern:
*"To create $c(m+1)$ from $c(m)$ replace the trailing $1$ by a $6$ and concat the string of entries (except the second-last) in reverse"* such that we have

```
c(3)=[0;1424  41 ]
c(4)=[0;1424  46  4241 ]
```

and from $c(4)$ to $c(5)$ the pattern of generating is the same:

```
c(4)=[0;14244642   41]
c(5)=[0;14244642   46   24644241]
```

So it seems, the whole infinite string of entries can be defined by a recursive "string"-operation.
I've seen one time an arcticle, which considers more of such recursive patterns in the entries of continued fractions and especially that mirroring to the reverse order when concatenating - but I don't remember the author.

Answer (score 0):

Since the ratio test can be applied, we know there exists the limit L.

Now we can say $a_n=a_{n+1}$ for $n\to\infty$.

If you are just looking for a close approximation, take wolfram alpha https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%281%2F2^2^k%29

Note that after k=3 nothing dramatic happens anymore, since the fraction gets so small very quickly

I don't know exactly if it can be applied here, but maybe *adic* expansion might help here too (preferably, like Helms said base 2)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Of course I've tried W/A and have seen the first few entries, but no idea how they might be continued. I've recovered an article of J. Shallit on continued fraction where he discusses such a pattern of entries for the continued fraction, however of a constant with $3$ in the bases of the series-terms instead of $2$ - and also no recipe how to compute that entries easily.

Comment: how far out have you calculated the continued fraction?

Comment: @Lubin - please see my edited question